# struts annotation issue

Tags: java, struts2

My issue is that I have an annotation in Struts2 action class like

```
private String[] origfilenofrom;

@FieldExpressionValidator(fieldName="origfilenofrom",key="",message="File Length should be 12 for old file format and 15 for new file format",expression="checkorigFileFormat(origfilenofrom)")
```

Now my method is

```
public boolean checkorigFileFormat(String[] files )
 {   
  for(int counter=0;counter<files.length;counter++)
     {
   int n=files[counter].length();
   if(!(n==12 || n==15))
   {
    return false;
   }
     }
     return true;
 }
```

So for any string in that string [], which is returning false the value is being false.
No matter 3 strings in that string [] are true if one is false then the annotation message is displayed for all.

I want the message not to display where the string is true.

Comment: so none can answer this...is this a Problem with Struts 2 design framework..??....any comments

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to answer.
I think you need to use validate method instead of annotation.

```
@Override
public void validate() {
 int count =0;
 for(String s : origfilenofrom)
   {
    if (!(s.length()==12 || s.length()==15)) {

    this.addActionError("File Length should be 12 for old file format and 15 for new file format for file no :"+ count);
      }
    count++;
   }
 }
```